# elasticsearch head not showing any data or getting connected

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-head

I have upgraded to elasticsearch 2.0.0 in my system and installed the elasticsearch-head plugin. But it is not getting connected and hence no display of the indices residing in my es server. 
Im able to index documents and display them via CURL. 
I have tried editing the elasticsearch.yml file like below:

```
http:cors.enabled : true
```

But this also seems not working.
Any idea,of why this is happening?.

Comment: You have a typo. can you try `http.cors.enabled: true`?

Comment: yep i did use that,but in vain..the typo got in only when I posted here.

Comment: Do you see any Javascript error if you open the developer console of your browser?

Comment: i am getting Cross-Origin Request issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `http.cors.allow-origin` explicitly since [there is no default value anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_cors_allowed_origins) since ES 2.0. Previously, that setting was set to `*` but that was considered a bad practice from the security point of view.

```
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
```